# Extract a string from a file and store it in a variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed, text-parsing

I have a file that has the below line in it.

```
ARG VERSION="6.0.0" // Here 6.0.0 is the version and could be any number.
```

I have a need to extract this value 6.0.0 and store it as a shell variable to be later used in the build.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is source an option?

https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/

you could add export to each config and just execute source on the file.

Alternatively,

    export $(xargs < myconfigfile)

would process them all.  

This won't work if you are only trying to process a single value in the config, both solutions would run against the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/ARG VERSION="[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/ARG VERSION="[^"]*/){            ##Using match function to match regex ARG VERSION=" till " here.
  print substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)    ##Printing sub-string of current line starting point is RSTART ending point is RLENGTH.
}
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -nE 's/ARG VERSION=\"(.*)\"/\1/p' <file_with_string>` may work.

In this case, we capture what is between double quotes, select that first capture group(`\1`) and print(`p`)